# How can I set notifications for gmail on the new version of the gmail app (2.3.5.2)

Tags: notifications, gmail

I recently installed CM7.1 (stable version for SGS).  This has a new version of the gmail app (2.3.5.2).  Unlike previous versions, this has no control for notifications.  I like my mail to arrive silently, with nothing more than an icon in the notification bar.  Now, however, I have no visible option to turn off the notification for gmail.

Is there any way to disable notifications for the gmail app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, with 2.3.5.x version of Gmail app, Google added more notification options, although well hidden within the settings.  In the main screen of the Gmail app:

1. Press the Menu key, go to More -> Settings.
2. Tap on your Google account, scroll down to the `Notification settings` section and ensure the `Email notifications` option is enabled.
3. On the same screen, tap on the `Labels to notify` option.  Here "Inbox" and "Priority Inbox" are always listed, as well as any labels you've created on the Gmail's web interface.
4. For each label that you want to specify or change notification options, tap on the label, and in the pop-up window you will be able to select the following options:

   - **Email notifications**: whether or not to display the icon in the notification area when new e-mail comes in.
   - **Ringtone**: allows you to specify a custom ringtone, or set to "Silent" for none.
   - **Vibrate**: specifies options for when/if to also vibrate on new mail.
   - **Notify once**: when checked, will only display notifications (and sound/vibrate) once for new mail until you dismiss it, otherwise will notify for each new e-mail.
5. Tap `OK` button, exit out of the settings, and you should be all set.